# PCA and data normalization

Tags: pca, normalization, dimensionality-reduction

I have a database where the number of features is about 60 times greater than the number of samples (60000 to 1000). I want to use some dimensional reduction techniques, including PCA.

Data are all on the same 'unit of measure' (they are RNA-exp data), but they have very different scales (std from about 0 to about 1e9) and magnitudes.
Obviously, scaling or not scaling the data leads to very different results for PCA (in particular, only about 15 components are enough to explain 99% of variance if one does not scale the data, while about 500 are needed if one does).
I understand the reason behind this behavior.

My question is: in this setting (same "unit", different magnitude), is it generally recommended to scale the data or not? The ultimate goal is to use PCs as features of a classifier.

Is there a general rule of thumb? How should one decide? 
Should one consider something else in case another technique (say LDA) is used for dimensionality reduction?

Thanks

Comment: Generally, yes, you should at least scale (if not completely standardize) your data before running PCA.  R packages that implement PCA or PCR often have a `scale` option in their input.

Comment: I would have done that for sure if variables were in different units or represented different things (ex: weight, age). My doubt here comes from the fact that variables represent the exact same thing (gene expression quantification). I remember a didactic example on pixels' degree of grey in a b/w picture in which scaling was not recommended as it was considered a loss of information. Isn't this a similar situation?

Comment: Ah, this problem makes more sense now.  This is a good question.  So your independent variables are measurements of the same type of observation (gene expression level, or something) but the magnitudes vary greatly between the different genes you are measuring?

Comment: Exactly. Means range from e-2 to e+8 and something similar (0, e+8) applies for std. 

(Btw it might be that in this particular case some genes are actually supposed to have higher values  for some reason - and I don't know since I'm not a domain expert - but consider a general case in which they are not, so that, in fact, independent variables are measurements of the same type of observations with different magnitudes and std)